# localStorage array sorting

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, local-storage

When coding a basic game for my school project I ran into a problem trying to store and sort a **highscore** array, I believe that the use of **localstorage** is the right way to go but as the array itself consists of a name and a score I've had issues when trying to sort it.

https://jsbin.com/fagupohozo/1/edit?js

```
    allPlayers = {};

function showScore(){
    getStoragePlayer();
    addPlayer();
    setStoragePlayer();
}

function addPlayer(){ //Adds a player to the array with score and name
    allPlayers[prompt("What's your name")] = score;
}

function setStoragePlayer(){ // Sends the array to the cloud for saving
    localStorage.setItem("PlayerArray", JSON.stringify(allPlayers));
}

function getStoragePlayer() { // Downloads the array from the cloud
    if (localStorage.PlayerArray != null) {
        allPlayers = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("PlayerArray"));
    }
}
```

Comment: For clarification the the thing I can't seem to do is sort the array by score after the current player is added to the array

Comment: There's nothing in your code that will even try to sort the array.  Please post the code you have so far to attempt to sort it.

Comment: You only show some function, where do you call them? Show us where you use those function, where is the error and what is the desired output so people can try to help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add allPlayers as array of objects like

```js
allPlayers = [
  {name:"John", score:20},
  {name:"Smith", score:40}
]
```

and then sort it with score so that you will get high score as well as name of that player in sorted array

```js
var allPlayers = [
      {name:"John", score:20},
      {name:"Smith", score:40}
    ];

    var sortedPlayers = allPlayers.sort(function(a, b){
      return b.score - a.score
    });
    console.log(sortedPlayers);
```

"sortedPlayers"  will contain sorted array with highest score at top